# mgcv: How to set number and / or locations of knots for splines

Tags: r, regression, spline, gam, mgcv

I want to use function `gam` in `mgcv` packages:

```
 x <- seq(0,60, len =600)
 y <- seq(0,1, len=600) 
 prova <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs='cr')
```

can I set the **number** of knots in `s()`? and then can I know where are the knots that the spline used? Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

While setting `k` is the correct way to go, `fx = TRUE` is definitely not right: it will force using pure regression spline without penalization.

---

**locations of knots**

For penalized regression spline, the exact locations are not important, as long as:

- `k` is adequately big;
- the spread of knots has good, reasonable coverage.

By default:

- natural cubic regression spline `bs = 'cr'` places knots by **quantile**;
- B-splines family (`bs = 'bs'`, `bs = 'ps'`, `bs = 'ad'`) place knots **evenly**.

Compare the following:

```
library(mgcv)

## toy data
set.seed(0); x <- sort(rnorm(400, 0, pi))  ## note, my x are not uniformly sampled
set.seed(1); e <- rnorm(400, 0, 0.4)
y0 <- sin(x) + 0.2 * x + cos(abs(x))
y <- y0 + e

## fitting natural cubic spline
cr_fit <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs = 'cr', k = 20))
cr_knots <- cr_fit$smooth[[1]]$xp  ## extract knots locations

## fitting B-spline
bs_fit <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs = 'bs', k = 20))
bs_knots <- bs_fit$smooth[[1]]$knots  ## extract knots locations

## summary plot
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(x, y, col= "grey", main = "natural cubic spline");
lines(x, cr_fit$linear.predictors, col = 2, lwd = 2)
abline(v = cr_knots, lty = 2)
plot(x, y, col= "grey", main = "B-spline");
lines(x, bs_fit$linear.predictors, col = 2, lwd = 2)
abline(v = bs_knots, lty = 2)
```

[image]

You can see the difference in knots placement.

---

**Setting your own knots locations:**

You can also provide your customized knots locations via the `knots` argument of `gam()` (yes, knots are not fed to `s()`, but to `gam()`). For example, you can do evenly spaced knots for `cr`:

```
xlim <- range(x)  ## get range of x
myfit <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs = 'cr', k = 20),
         knots = list(x = seq(xlim[1], xlim[2], length = 20)))
```

Now you can see that:

```
my_knots <- myfit$smooth[[1]]$xp
plot(x, y, col= "grey", main = "my knots");
lines(x, myfit$linear.predictors, col = 2, lwd = 2)
abline(v = my_knots, lty = 2)
```

[image]

However, there is usually no need to set knots yourself. But if you do want to do this, you must be clear what you are doing. In particular, **the number of knots you provide must not conflict with the `k` in `s()`**.

> This is a very rich answer. The length of `bs_knots` is 24. The "dimension" of the spline basis is in `bs_fit$smooth[[1]]$bs.dim`, which is 20.

Yes, for B-splines family, the number of B-splines does not equal the number of knots. Knots placement for B-splines is a dirty work and error-prone. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72723391/4891738 for a demonstration with B-splines.

Comment: This is a very rich answer. The length of `bs_knots` is 24. The "dimension" of the spline basis is in `bs_fit$smooth[[1]]$bs.dim`.

Comment: @李哲源 Thanks for the detailed answer. Is there a way to extract the knots without calling `gam`, e.g. by calling `smoothCon`?

Comment: @papgeo Say `x <- runif(100); sm <- smoothCon(s(x, bs = 'cr', k = 20), data = data.frame(x = x), knots = NULL); sm[[1]]$xp` Note that if you use `smoothCon`, you can directly set `knots` (but it needs match `k`). `knots = FALSE` will do auto knots placement.

Comment: @李哲源 Thank you very much. I see 20 knots in the code you provided. But when I try `smoothCon(s(x, bs = 'cr', k = 20), data = data.frame(x = x), knots = seq(0,1,length.out=20))` it gives me an error message: Error in data[[txt]] : subscript out of bounds.

Comment: @papgeo `smoothCon(s(x, bs = 'cr', k = 20), data = data.frame(x = x), knots = list(x = seq(0,1,length.out=20)))` Knots need be provided in a list. This makes sense as when constructing multivariate splines like tensor product splines, each variable has a set of knots and they should be given in a list.