# Fitting a smooth spline (GAM function) in R: Error in number of knots required to fit spline -- knot requirements increasing

Tags: r, regression, spline, gam, mgcv

I'm trying to fit a smooth spline to what looks like data with two peaks. First, I fit a smooth spline to my data to identify the potential position of the knots.

```
library(npreg)
library(splines)
library(mgcv)

x <- c(20.70, 20.44, 20.58, 21.02, 19.90,  6.20,  8.20,  6.92,  5.86,  6.44,  6.34,  8.48,  8.46,  9.00,  9.06,  9.00,  9.06, 17.98, 18.42, 19.18, 22.88, 24.16,20.20, 23.50)

y <- c(19.884208, 12.772114, 12.932944,  5.016790, 11.405843,  3.310724,  3.950049,  3.641571,  4.073783,  4.616096,  3.425635,  7.773548,  7.498084, 9.474213,  6.162779, 11.041210, 12.618555,  6.287967,  4.286919,  3.242361,  7.571644,  3.379709,  5.274434,  8.8258)


data = data.frame(x,y)

fit_spline <- smooth.spline(x,y)
plot(x,y)
lines(fit_spline,lwd=2,col="purple")
```

[image]

Then, I wanted to run a regression using the gam function where I can specify the position of the knots. I get an error that says `Error in smooth.construct.bs.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) : there should be  7  supplied knots` I am not sure where it's drawing this number. If I supply 7 knots, it says it needs 13 knots...and the same erorr gets repeated. I am unclear on how to proceed.

```
myfit <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs = 'bs', k = 3),
             knots = list(x = c(1,5,20)))

my_knots <- myfit$smooth[[1]]$xp
plot(x, y, col= "grey", main = "my knots");
lines(x, myfit$linear.predictors, col = 2, lwd = 2)
abline(v = my_knots, lty = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you came from one of my previous answer in 2016: [mgcv: How to set number and / or locations of knots for splines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40113075/4891738), borrowing my code snippet:

```
my_knots <- myfit$smooth[[1]]$xp
plot(x, y, col= "grey", main = "my knots");
lines(x, myfit$linear.predictors, col = 2, lwd = 2)
abline(v = my_knots, lty = 2)
```

In that answer, my demonstration was made with cubic regression spline (`bs = 'cr'`), where knot placement is simple to do. But for B-splines, things are more complicated. So take this answer as a complement to that answer.

---

For B-spline classes in **mgcv**, i.e., `'bs'` being "bs" (`?b.spline`), "ps" (`?p.spline`) or "ad" (`?adaptive.smooth`), the argument `k` is the number of B-splines, not the number of knots. And the first take-home message is: **the number of B-splines is NOT equal to the number of knots.**

Knot placement for B-splines is a dirty work. Usually you only specify `k` and **mgcv** will place knots automatically for you (see for example, [Extract knots, basis, coefficients and predictions for P-splines in adaptive smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37379609/4891738)). If you want to control knot placement yourself, the number of knots you provide must be compatible with `k`. This can cause great confusion if you don't well understand B-splines.

I highly recommend your reading the Appendix (page 33-34) of one of my work: [General P-splines for Non-uniform B-splines](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.06808.pdf), to know some fundamental stuff of B-splines. Make sure you understand what are the **domain**, **interior knots** and **auxiliary boundary knots**. In the following, I will just show you how to use these knowledge to write the correct code.

---

Here is how to place knots for your example.

```
## degree of spline
deg <- 3

## domain
a <- min(x)
#[1] 5.86
b <- max(x)
#[1] 24.16

## interior knots (must be between a and b)
xs <- c(6, 20)
#[1]  6 20

## domain knots
xd <- c(a, xs, b)
#[1]  5.86  6.00 20.00 24.16

## clamped auxiliary boundary knots
left.aux <- rep(a, deg)
#[1] 5.86 5.86 5.86
right.aux <- rep(b, deg)
#[1] 24.16 24.16 24.16

## complete B-spline knots
my.knots <- c(left.aux, xd, right.aux)
#[1]  5.86  5.86  5.86  5.86  6.00 20.00 24.16 24.16 24.16 24.16
```

Here is how to specify `k` for your example.

```
my.k <- length(xs) + deg + 1
#[1] 6
```

Now we can work with **mgcv**.

```
myfit <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs = 'bs', k = my.k),
             knots = list(x = my.knots))
#Family: gaussian 
#Link function: identity
#
#Formula:
#y ~ s(x, bs = "bs", k = my.k, m = deg)
#
#Estimated degrees of freedom:
#3.81  total = 4.81
```

The knots you passed in are stored here (which agree with `my.knots`):

```
## For B-spline classes, knots are stored in $knots instead of $xp
myfit$smooth[[1]]$knots
#[1]  5.86  5.86  5.86  5.86  6.00 20.00 24.16 24.16 24.16 24.16
```

---

Accompanying [General P-splines for Non-uniform B-splines](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.06808.pdf) are R packages **gps** and **gps.mgcv**. The latter package introduces a new "gps" class to **mgcv**, where `bs = 'ps'` and `bs = 'bs'` are special cases of `bs = 'gps'`. The new "gps" class makes knot placement easier, because it automatically places auxiliary boundary knots for you and you only need to provide interior knots.

```
## The package stays on GitHub for the moment
## but will be on CRAN in the future.
## You may need to first install package 'devtools' from CRAN.
devtools::install_github("ZheyuanLi/gps")
devtools::install_github("ZheyuanLi/gps.mgcv")
```

```
library(gps.mgcv)

## as same as using 'bs = 'bs''
myfit <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs = 'gps', k = my.k, xt = list(derivative = TRUE)),
             knots = list(x = xs))  ## provide interior knots

## the novel general P-spline
gpsfit <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs = 'gps', k = my.k),
             knots = list(x = xs))  ## provide interior knots
```

Construction information (domain, interior knots, etc) are stored in `myfit$smooth[[1]]$xt` and `gpsfit$smooth[[1]]$xt`.

Comment: Thankyou! I am slowly working though your code. I am trying to install your packages from github and I get the error `ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` Any ideas on how can I resolve it?